# PHP exec iconv doesn't work

Tags: php, encoding, exec

I have an .sh script and an iconv command inside. I can't use the PHP iconv function. I don't knwo why but with my script the iconv command doesn't do anything.

It's creating an empty file without my original content.

```
iconv -f ascii -t utf-16 "list_temp.txt" > "list.txt"
```

list_temptxt is encoded in ASCII and contains some content. After the execution list.txt is empty.
If I execute my shell script through the terminal there're no problems ...

Anyone ?

Comment: You may need to adjust your paths, the path in which php executes may not be where the file exists.

Comment: Check your permissions on the file.

Comment: But the file list.txt is created by calling the iconv cmd ...